# Remove weekday from Gnome title bar

Tags: linux, gnome

I'm using GNOME Shell 3.26.2 on Fedora 26.

The date and time area on the title bar shows the week day:

[image]

I want to get rid of the weekday. How do I proceed?

- Settings > Details > Date & time lets me change the date but not change how the date is displayed (save for picking the "AM/PM" vs "24hs" format).
- Installing `gnome-tweak-tool` I can hide the seconds and the month name and day of the month, but not the day of the week.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

from gnome-tweak tool, get more extensions...
get and enable "Datetime format" extension

enter the extension settings by clicking on the little cog next to "Datetime format"

click the cog next to the "status bar" option, and enter

```
%B %y, %R   #many other options available to customise it further
```

into the format text box, green tick to accept, log out and login, 
you should be good